# How to get number of edits made by a user in freebase?

Tags: freebase, mql, freebase-acre

I am trying to get number of topics added, edited and deleted by certain users.

I am able to get number of topics using following query:

```
[{
  "creator":     "/user/getsaurabhsaxena",
  "name":        null,
  "id":          null,
  "mid":         null,
  "type": [{
    "name": null,
    "id":   null
  }],
  "timestamp>=": "2012-11-11T00:00:00.0000Z",
  "timestamp<=": "2012-12-12T23:23:59.0000Z",
  "timestamp":   null,
  "sort":        "-timestamp"
}]​
```

I am not able to figure out the way to get the number of edits and deletions. Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

operation property has three values insert, delete and update by which you can get number of additions, deletions and updates. :)
I am using following query for the same.

```
[{
  "operation":     null,
  "source": {
  },
  "from:timestamp>=": "2012-11-12T00:00:00.000Z",
  "to:timestamp<": "2012-12-12T23:23:59.000Z",
  "attribution":   "/user/<username>",
  "timestamp":     null,
  "sort":          "-timestamp",
  "type":          "/type/link",
  "limit":         1000
}]​
```